# Scenario - How to parse alphanumeric words based on vocabulary/literature

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

I have the following two text scenarios -

Text = "Boy000"
Text_2 = "3D"

**the outputs I seek is Text = Boy and Text_2 = 3D**

My current code is as follows

```
sent_punc.translate(remove_digits).replace('  ',' ')
```

however, this leads to - Boy and D

Comment: So you only want to remove digits at the end of the string?

Comment: Thank you for responding. It's more like a strategy to remove digits if the alphanumeric word doesn't make sense or isn't part of some literature. 

Example - 

Boy00 = Boy,
B00oy = Boy,
00Boy = Boy
3D = 3D

Comment: Check for the string in `/usr/share/dict/words` and apply if not found.  I note that it contains both "Boy" and "3D".

Comment: How do I craft this code for windows os 

wordlist = [line.strip() for line in open('/usr/share/dict/words')] ??